# Conditional datatable row color using domino-ui

Tags: java, user-interface, datatable, gwt, domino-ui

Can we change the background color of a domino-ui datatable row based on some expression or a condition? for example make the row background red if DueDate < Today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domino-ui datatable has a built-in plugin called Marker plugin that can mark the row conditionally with different colors, the plugin adds the color as a border to the left border of the row

[image]

you can find an example in domino-ui demo [here](https://demo.dominokit.org/datatable/marker-plugin)

and if that is not enough you can create your own plugin, like this

```
import elemental2.dom.HTMLTableRowElement;
import org.dominokit.domino.ui.datatable.DataTable;
import org.dominokit.domino.ui.datatable.TableRow;
import org.dominokit.domino.ui.datatable.plugins.DataTablePlugin;

public class RowColorPlugin<T> implements DataTablePlugin<T> {

    @Override
    public void onRowAdded(DataTable<T> dataTable, TableRow<T> tableRow) {
        T record = tableRow.getRecord();
        HTMLTableRowElement row = tableRow.element();
        // Add css classes or set css properties in the row element based on the row record to change the row colors
    }
}
```

And here is a sample showing how to use the custom plugin

```
TableConfig<Contact> tableConfig = new TableConfig<>();
        tableConfig
                .addColumn(ColumnConfig.<Contact>create("id", "#")
                        .textAlign("right")
                        .asHeader()
                        .setCellRenderer(cell -> TextNode.of(cell.getTableRow().getRecord().getIndex() + 1 + "")))

                .addColumn(ColumnConfig.<Contact>create("status", "Status")
                        .textAlign("center")
                        .setCellRenderer(cell -> {
                            if (cell.getTableRow().getRecord().isActive()) {
                                return Style.of(Icons.ALL.check_circle()).setColor(Color.GREEN_DARKEN_3.getHex()).element();
                            } else {
                                return Style.of(Icons.ALL.highlight_off()).setColor(Color.RED_DARKEN_3.getHex()).element();
                            }
                        }))
                .addColumn(ColumnConfig.<Contact>create("firstName", "First name")
                        .setCellRenderer(cell -> TextNode.of(cell.getTableRow().getRecord().getName())))


                .addColumn(ColumnConfig.<Contact>create("gender", "Gender")
                        .setCellRenderer(cell -> ContactUiUtils.getGenderElement(cell.getRecord()))
                        .textAlign("center"))

                .addColumn(ColumnConfig.<Contact>create("eyeColor", "Eye color")
                        .setCellRenderer(cell -> ContactUiUtils.getEyeColorElement(cell.getRecord()))
                        .textAlign("center"))

                .addColumn(ColumnConfig.<Contact>create("balance", "Balance")
                        .setCellRenderer(cellInfo -> ContactUiUtils.getBalanceElement(cellInfo.getRecord())))

                .addColumn(ColumnConfig.<Contact>create("email", "Email")
                        .setCellRenderer(cell -> TextNode.of(cell.getTableRow().getRecord().getEmail())))

                .addColumn(ColumnConfig.<Contact>create("phone", "Phone")
                        .setCellRenderer(cell -> TextNode.of(cell.getTableRow().getRecord().getPhone())))

                .addColumn(ColumnConfig.<Contact>create("badges", "Badges")
                        .setCellRenderer(cell -> {
                            if (cell.getTableRow().getRecord().getAge() < 35) {
                                return Badge.create("Young")
                                        .setBackground(ColorScheme.GREEN.color()).element();
                            }
                            return TextNode.of("");
                        }));

        tableConfig.addPlugin(new RowColorPlugin<>(tableCellInfo -> ContactUiUtils.getBalanceColor(tableCellInfo.getRecord())));
        LocalListDataStore<Contact> localListDataStore = new LocalListDataStore<>();
        DataTable<Contact> defaultTable = new DataTable<>(tableConfig, localListDataStore);
    localListDataStore.setData(contactsList);
```